# Firefox and Chromium not opening

Tags: permissions

Firefox and Chromium do not open any longer. I fixed firefox by re-installing the snap. But re-installing chromium-browser did not help.

The error points to permission issues. What is the correct permission for the files and how could they have changed?

```
chromium-browser 
/snap/chromium/2011/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 52: /home/username/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
sed: can't read /home/username/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/snap/chromium/2011/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 261: /home/username/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
cp: cannot open '/home/username/.config/user-dirs.locale' for reading: Permission denied
/snap/chromium/2011/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 266: /home/username/.config/user-dirs.locale: Permission denied
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

-rw------- 1 username username 633 Apr 24  2020 /home/username/.config/user-dirs.dirs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   5 Apr 24  2020 /home/username/.config/user-dirs.locale
```

Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it; purge was essential

```
sudo snap remove --purge chromium
```